# algorithm2e: Applying color to an entire line, excluding the line number

Tags: color, algorithm2e

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[boxed, noline, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \textcolor{red}{\If{test}{\KwRet $-1$\;}}
    blah\;
    blah\;
    blah\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: sample output with colored line numbers]

As you can see, not only the lines, but also the line numbers are drawn in red. I want to apply the red color only to lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set/change the way the numbering is formatted. And, in this case, reformat it to set it using `\color{black}`. The macro provided to set this is `\SetNlSty`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[boxed, noline, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\SetNlSty{bfseries}{\color{black}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
    \textcolor{red}{\If{test}{\KwRet $-1$\;}}
    blah\;
    blah\;
    blah\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The reason for the somewhat bizarre formatting choices when using `\SetNlSty` stems from its definition in [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty), together with the default of `\NlSty`:

```
\newcommand{\NlSty}[1]
  {\textnormal{\textbf{\relsize{\algocf@nlrelsize}#1}}}% default definition
\newcommand{\SetNlSty}[3]{\renewcommand{\NlSty}[1]
  {\textnormal{\csname#1\endcsname{\relsize{\algocf@nlrelsize}#2##1#3}}}}%
```